# InvalidArgumentException: The service definition "security.encoder_factory.responses" does not exist

Tags: symfony, service

I have a really strange error in a symfony 2 installation. 
Everything worked fine until I suddenly ran into this error. The cache cannot be cleared because of the error, which is also preventing me from checking/updating dependencies with Composer.

> InvalidArgumentException: The service definition "security.encoder_factory.responses" does not exist

I tried to manually clear the cache (removing the folder, recreating it and setup permissions again) without succes. The error persists and is the result of every request even when a new cache is build.

Is there anybody with a suggestion as to where to look, or how to solve this problem?

The proposed grep of Pazi (see comments) gave no results, zero.

Comment: What have you done before this error (your last action)?

Comment: Added some minor changes to the code (basically string manipulation).

Comment: Did you modify any services definitions? The error means that a service which doesn't exist is requested to inject. A `security.encoder_factory` does exist. Maybe you changed to much?

Comment: Where would I have changed that? Where should I look, I only changed some controller code...

Comment: IDK. Can you grep for this in your project dir and edit the result into your question? `grep -rnE "security.encoder_factory.responses" *`

Comment: Im doing that right now.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. What's with the permissions of the cache folder?

Comment: 777 Isn't that supposed to be?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29927/discussion-between-pazi-and-quant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed to be a *magic* dependency error. After clearing the `vendor/` directory, removing the `composer.lock` file and installing vendors from scratch (with `update`) it works again.

Maybe it was a not correctly updated autoloader from composer or not complete deleted vendor after removing from composer.json. Sometime magic happens :)